# android pass html sting to different activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass html data between 2 activity.I got an idea that I just pass the object value and than after manage this object in second activity, for that I got solution from stack and other blogs which is

```
    Pages objPages= list.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PagesContentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Content",  objPages);
```

But I couldn't success to pass the object value. Is there any mistake? I have idea of static variable but I don't want this as solution. Is there any other solution for pass object value?  I got problem when I try to pass object value **"The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Pages)"**

Comment: [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). You can't pass a Pages object to the extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) in the sending activity And  [Html.toHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml%28android.text.Spanned%29) in receiving activity

Comment: thanks Arun C Thomas for answer.. i just tried out Html.fromHtml  and let me try Html.toHtml..